# Making a meal plan/schedule for a cafeteria in a school

Tags: php, database, wordpress, schedule

I need to, via wordpress, make a site to be used by a school with the purpose of showing the day's mealplan. As a website you would be able to access it on any screen and show it on the info screens and so on.

What i need is a plugin or a way where i can make a form like this example:

Hot dishes

dish 1: enter here
dish 2: enter here
dish 3: enter here

Cold dishes

dish 1: enter here
dish 2: enter here
dish 3: enter here

Salads

1: enter here

Bread

1: enter here

and so on. So that the kitchen's chef can enter a bunch of days in on the same page via a form, that then stores the information in the database and can be shown on a page with styling. So that the current day's menu will be pulled from db and displayed, manually or automatically.
My main concern is getting this to be dynamic and via a database. There is a very crappy temporary solution in place now with one whole page per day. That would mean a website with 365 pages minus the weeekends. And any editing or styling needs to be done on each page. Simply not viable.

Does anyone have any ways, suggestions, plugins or the likes with which this could be done?

Comment: Too broad. We help resolve specific programming issues, not "how do I do this project" style ones.

Comment: @JonStirling Do you recommend that i formulate a much more precise description of my problem or that i take it elsewhere?

Comment: I'd suggest you try and build the application yourself by researching available libraries / packages for ones that will help and the just doing it. At that point if you have specific programming issues you're more than welcome to come back and ask. Otherwise it sounds more like you want to find a mentor, or yeah, ask on a more appropriate site (though I don't have any that I can think of that would fit this). Just starting working on it is definitely my suggestion though.

Answer (score 0):

For these kind of things [toolset](https://toolset.com/) is fantastic. You have a good chance to realize it all without a line of (PHP) code. It does have a learning curve, but is certainly much easier than coding it (especially if you have to ask this question ;-))